# Why am I automatically picking up drops when I kill monsters?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In some situations, such as knocking a monster out of a minecart into lava, I automatically get the drops, even though the items are far away. I'm not sure what the cause of this is. Perhaps it happens when you kill a monster with a sage ability?

Exact situation (light spoilers for Goron portion of Regional Phenonema):

> I used Yunobo to launch a Soldier Construct IV from its minecart into lava in the Fire Temple. I also did the same with two Rock Octoroks on the minecart track up Eldin Volcano.

Comment: Not a surefire answer, but I've mainly seen this happen when the drops fall in an otherwise inaccessible location (like lava) or it drops outside of a certain distance from Link's position

Comment: Can confirm this, when I kill Aerocudas high in air I often get their drop automatically

Comment: I don't think this is the case, as I hit a different Soldier IV into lava with a melee attack and I didn't get the drops.

Comment: My experience matches what @Wondercricket described, it seems  to happen when an item becomes inaccessible to grab. However, I've also noticed it isn't full proof... I've definitely lost items that were not retrievable, where I did not auto-collect them.

Comment: When you are on a vehicle, you get the drops automatically, even when (or especially) when it is your companion that gets the kill.